# Starting a Java Thread with a Runnable opens a new small popup for the process. How can I avoid the popup?

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, jtextarea, runnable

I have implemented a JTextArea which acts like an area that constantly reads the output of a log file from another process and presents it to the user.

Here's a sample of my code:

```
class CustomOutputStream extends OutputStream {
    private JTextArea textArea;
     
    public CustomOutputStream(JTextArea textArea) {
        this.textArea = textArea;
    }
     
    @Override
    public void write(int b) throws IOException {
        // redirects data to the text area
        textArea.append(String.valueOf((char)b));
        // scrolls the text area to the end of data
        textArea.setCaretPosition(textArea.getDocument().getLength());
    }
}

class TextAreaLogProgram extends JFrame {
    /**
     * The text area which is used for displaying logging information.
     */
    private JTextArea textArea;
     
    public TextAreaLogProgram() {
        // the formEnvironment is part of install4j
        textArea = ((JTextArea)formEnvironment.getFormComponentById("3341").getConfigurationObject());
        
        PrintStream printStream = new PrintStream(new CustomOutputStream(textArea));
 
         printLog();
         
    }
     
    /**
     * Prints log statements in a thread
     */
    private void printLog() {
        Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
            
                while (true) {
                    // A whole lot of regex matching is done here to present the info that we want
                    // to the user and once we reach the end I break
                        break;
                    }
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(100);
                    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        thread.start();
    }
 }

// Start the whole thing by making it visible.It's hidden by default
new TextAreaLogProgram().setVisible(true);
```

Now the above code adds a small "annoying" popup on the top left corner that has no content and just the usual Maximize and Close buttons attached to it with the Java icon on the left side. Like this:

[annoying popup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y4KM3.png)

Is there a way to do everything I'm doing right now without that popup?

Thanks in advance everyone.

Comment: Why are you calling `setVisible(true)` if you don’t want the window to be visible?

Comment: I can't believe it was something as simple as this... You were absolutely right @VGR